# How to prevent remote branch deletion in git without using gitolite

Tags: linux, git

Is there any way to block deletion of remote branches?

I want to block deletion of remote branches but normal flow like code checking and check out should work fine!!

without using gitolite! is it possible ?

please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just add a suitable server side git hook.

You probably want to use a pre-receive hook. For details have a look at [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) or [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).

Example:

```
#create repositories
git init a
git init --bare b

#add the hook in "b"
echo -e '#!/usr/bin/bash\nread old new ref\ntest $new != 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' >>b/hooks/pre-receive
chmod +x b/hooks/pre-receive

#create a commit in "a"
cd a
echo foo >test
git add .
git commit -m testcommit

#push it to "b"
git push ../b master

#try to delete remote branch
git push ../b :master
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 refs/heads/*,delete)
       # delete branch
              if [ "$allowdeletebranch" != "true" ]; then
                echo "*** Deleting a branch is not allowed in this repository" >&2
                    exit 1
                fi
```

adding this in update hook solved my problem 
Hope this will help someone else too

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you're avoiding gitolite (which is sort of the end point of all access control, as it were), but I have a sample pre-receive script [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt) that uses hooks.* git config entries to do some simple access controls.  It's not as fancy as gitolite but it does some things I cared about once. :-)

Comment: `NOTE: BARELY TESTED` well, that inspires confidence =). IMO Using gitolote or similar when it's not necssary is simply a waste of effort/time; when all you need is one hook - changing everything is a very intrusive way to achieve that.