# Is code safe in git repository on a remote server? How to secure it?

Tags: git, version-control, collaboration

We have a server that hosts git repositories for our projects and we are letting external programmers in to work on our codebase.

We were surprised that git doesn't protect the code history as typical code repository technology should do ([see bullet 7.](http://steveko.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/10-things-i-hate-about-git/)) and we are afraid that external programmers can potentially destroy code in the central repository (but we are not sure as Git is pretty complex :)

Is it possible for user to destroy data in remote repository? And how to protect such remote?

We are using Gitolite to control access to the repositories hosted on a server.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible for a user to *destroy* data, in that you could always recover it before any orphans are garbage-collected. Note this originally said *recover it from the reflog* but, as sleske points out, that isn't enabled on bare repos by default.

Even if you enable the reflog for easier recovery, it's better to prevent this damage in the first place.

Suggested ways of losing data from the linked blog are:

1. git add . / … / git push -f origin master
2. git push origin +master
3. git rebase -i  / git push

All of these boil down to some non-fast-forward update to master, which generally needs to be forced explicitly (with `-f`). You should be able to prevent this with a [server-side hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks), specifically the pre-receive hook.

---

[This](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/1327469) should cover you, although there's more in there than you asked for. Just make sure `git config --bool hooks.allownonffpush` is `false`.

Comment: Note that reflogs are *disabled* by default on bare git repos (what you'd typically use on a git server). In that case you can *not* recover commits from the reflog. You can still rummage around in the object database, but that could be quite painful.

Answer (score 2):

You need a different work flow if you fear that external programmers will destroy data.  Some points:

1) Ignoring repository history, external programmers can 'zero out' the source code in all branches that they have access to.  They do that by removing all the source code in their local repository and then pushing the now empty change to your repository.  You can recover from that but it can be painful

2) External programmers can 'force commit' destructive changes that rewrite history.  Git warns about this but unless you've configured your repository to forbid it, they can do it.

I suggest that an improved workflow would be that each external programmer (or each organization with multiple programmers) have their own Git repository.  Your external programmers makes changes to their own Git repository.  When they are happy with the changes, they announce that they are ready to 'deliver' to you and then you merge their changes in their repository with your repository.  This is the GitHub pull request model.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can destroy data (more precisely, commits) in a remote git repository using just push access:

- doing a non-fast-forward push to a branch (`git push -f ...`)
- deleting a branch (`git push --delete ...`)

A non-fast-forward push is almost never a good idea with a shared repository, so you should just forbid it. This is done by running `git config --system receive.denyNonFastForwards true` on the server.

Deleting a branch is more tricky. Obviously deleting a branch may lose history; however for short-lived branches, personal branches, or branches that are fully merged, it makes sense as a "cleanup".

One solution would be to disallow branch deletion (see e.g. 
[How to prevent remote branch deletion in git without using gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293222/how-to-prevent-remote-branch-deletion-in-git-without-using-gitolite)), but allow branch renaming. Then people can rename an old branch "featureX" to something like "DELETE-featureX". You can later clean up these once it has been checked that the deletion is OK.

If you take these precautions, it is *not* possible to lose commits with just push access.

You might also want to look into some git wrapper such as [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) to better control repository access.

As to data loss: Real data loss should at any rate be very limited, because you can always retrieve one of the nightly backups you make. You have these, don't you?

Comment: We will use gitolite to restrict certain users access to some branches and will forbid non-fast-forward pushes globally. And yes, we have nightly backups. Thank you for summing it all up!